# PHP/MYSQL Delayed update query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i'm developing news portal using codeigniter, it's run well on my first hosting provider, but after i moved to a new hosting provider i started got this update query problem.

i'm using article read counter similar to below function, in my new hosting it got delayed for more than 10 second, so the counter has problem if more than one reader in a close time.

it's not mysql problem beacuse i've test it using direct query to mysql and all seems fine.

anybody knows why i'm having this?

```
$a=mysql_query("update tbarticle set a_views=a_views+1 where a_id='25405'");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT a_views FROM tbarticle where a_id='25405'") or die(mysql_error());  

$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
echo $row['a_views'];
```

Comment: When exactly does the delay happen? If it's when the code above runs, it *has* to be a mysql problem

Comment: I assume this code gets executed when the article page is requested?

Comment: If you are using CodeIgniter, you should be using the Database Class instead of the naive PHP MySQL functions.

Comment: When you switched hosting servers, did you also move the MySQL database and if so, did you update your connection string?

Comment: at first i thought it's about config problem, but then i tried to simulate condition using above script, using simple php and i still got the problem...


tanyamath.com/apus.php refresh couple times, and then wait more than 10 seconds, then refresh again it's above simple php mysql script

Comment: Using `mysql_query` is a very bad idea, especially when CodeIgnighter has [a much better system for doing this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/index.html).

Comment: that's just simulated my real condition... i wanna make sure is it codeigniter problem, mysql problem or php problem

Answer (score 0):

If you load the page cited in the comments in the original post:

http://tanyamath.com/apus.php

You see a count.  If you refresh the browser (hit F5 repeatedly), the counter does not change for anywhere from 10 to 20 seconds or refreshes.

When you connect to MySQL, if you use `mysql_connect()` instead of `mysql_pconnect()`, you may be running into a busy server trying to open a connection.   You may not have seen this problem earlier because the server was not as busy as your new host server.

Try using `mysql_pconnect()` and see if that helps.

Comment: my codeigniter using pconnect, but it has same problem.

i also monitoring mysql using SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST, and i'm sure it has nothing to do with resource

Comment: This is a curious one...  I wonder if the table is locking during update, which storage engine are you using?

Comment: i used myisam... using SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST i'm sure no table was locked

Comment: Would it be too much trouble to publish your code in GitHub?  Be sure to leave out any username/passwords.

Comment: i guess my script above clear enough, two lines before just mysql_connect and mysql_select_db

i'm sure it has nothing to do with my code, i've used it before in 4 different environtment...

this new hosting used litespeed which i never used before, but i'm not sure it's the problem

Comment: i check the http header and found the problem. it's varnish that cache all content and even ignore header no cache and must revalidate...

i guess i must contact my hosting provider then...

thanks for all response

Comment: It might be easier to find another host.  It sounds like the server may not have been configured in a standard way and it could lead to other problems down the road.  Glad you found the problem! Good luck with the project.